# svg graphic doesn't fit

Tags: css, svg

I am new to SVG and had someone create this code for me. My issue is that I cant modify the size of the blue graphics so the text fits in. Is there an easier way to create this graphic as the SVG examples I find look a lot simpler.

I tried changing the height/width but it did work as expected. The height doesn't change the height of the blue graphics but the width attribute changed the height?

```
http://andrewt.com.au/cta/
```

_

```
<div data-svg-id="c5364617a0184af19456d25c95059d8f.svg" data-svg-type="shape" data-display-mode="fit" data-strokewidth="0" data-viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-preserve-viewbox="ignore" class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9" id="comp-jjjncesq" style="left: px;width: 430px;position: absolute;top: 22px;height: 200px;"><div class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9_comp-jjjncesq SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9_non-scaling-stroke SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9svg" id="comp-jjjncesqsvg" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 0; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(7, 166, 252);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="18.5 63.106998443603516 163 74.78599548339844" role="img" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="stroke-width: 0px;">
    <g>
        <path d="M181.5 63.107h-163v62.978h129.423l17.206 10.897 1.436.911-.352-1.664-2.141-10.144H181.5V63.107z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
</div><div id="comp-jjjncesqlink" class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9link"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like styles were added to the SVG inline using `style="width: 250px"` In my example below, I've removed them and added the `my-svg` class. Using this class, you are able to specify the height and width.

```css
.my-svg {
  left: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div data-svg-id="c5364617a0184af19456d25c95059d8f.svg" data-svg-type="shape" data-display-mode="fit" data-strokewidth="0" data-viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-preserve-viewbox="ignore" class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9 my-svg" id="comp-jjjncesq">
  <div class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9_comp-jjjncesq SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9_non-scaling-stroke SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9svg" id="comp-jjjncesqsvg" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 0; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(7, 166, 252);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="18.5 63.106998443603516 163 74.78599548339844" role="img" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="stroke-width: 0px;">
    <g>
        <path d="M181.5 63.107h-163v62.978h129.423l17.206 10.897 1.436.911-.352-1.664-2.141-10.144H181.5V63.107z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
  </div>
  <div id="comp-jjjncesqlink" class="SvgShp0-ty9_hvnoyof9link"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this better but it doesnt change the height . If I change the height from your class the blue graphic doesnt change in any way? I tried this on the same link i provided on OP

Comment: ok i needed to add height/width in svg and this makes it easy to adjust